# Kernel crashes during training using tensorflow-directml

Tags: windows, tensorflow, installation, deep-learning

Currently training on Windows with RX 580 AMD so I had to use tensorflow-directml. It was working able train a very lightweight model but when I used a little bit complex model, kernel keeps on crashing on the first epoch. Error is:

> The DirectML device has encountered an unrecoverable error (DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED). This is most often caused by a timeout occurring on the GPU. Please visit https://aka.ms/tfdmltimeout for more information and troubleshooting steps.
> 2023-09-19 14:27:13.548745: F tensorflow/c/logging.cc:43] HRESULT failed with 0x887a0005: chunk->resource->Map(0, nullptr, &upload_heap_data)

I tried to adjust the TdrDelay = 10 and it still crashes. And I have set the `TF_DIRECTML_MAX_ALLOC_SIZE` and reduced the batch size. Im able to proceed when training using cpu but ofcourse it is so much slower but no runtime errors. What other steps can I do to resolve this?

[image]